# Use OAuth2 to sign in to client with spring boot using authorization_code grant and JWT

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, spring-security-oauth2

I'm trying to get a single sign on server/client thing going using JWT & OAuth2.

I have no resources to request from outside of the client other than the username (which I plan to just embed in the jwt).

My server is working and dealing out jwt tokens just fine (testing with postman's oauth2 token authentication). I just have no clue what to do with the client.

Do I need to make my client a ResourceServer? Or should I just go with the @EnableOAuth2Sso tutorials?

For my client I have the following specs:

- I would like to use the "authorization_code" grant type
- I want to hide all the pages of the client behind the oauth2 login

  - Users request a page, if they are not signed in (dont have a auth header with valid jwt token) they should be redirected to the authserver/oauth/authorize path
  - A login form is shown and the user logs in with username password
  - If the login is correct they get redirected back to the requested client page
- if the user comes back before the JWT expired, they should not have to log in again.
- I want to use Spring Security with as little custom code as possible.

I would assume this is possible and is exactly what Single Sign On should be.

My first thought was to use the @EnableOAuth2Sso but this does not work correctly:

1. I get redirected to the login page on the server
2. I login correctly
3. I get redirected to: http://localhost:9000/login?code=fmzhJ5&state=bn9077
4. I get this error: There was an unexpected error (type=Unauthorized, status=401).
   Authentication Failed: Could not obtain access token

### Update

I found the following error message: Possible CSRF detected - state parameter was required but no state could be found

I guess there is a misconfiguration saving/using/converting the "state" parameter. I would however like to use it.

### Update2

I found [this comment](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security-oauth/issues/322#issuecomment-64951927) and added a different context path for the client. This changed the error message to:

org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException: Could not obtain access token
Caused by: org.springframework.security.oauth2.client.resource.OAuth2AccessDeniedException: Error requesting access token.
Caused by: org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 null

Code:

**Client app**:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableOAuth2Sso
public class TestClientApplication
{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(TestClientApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**application.yml:**

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: client
      clientSecret: secret
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:8080/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:8080/oauth/authorize
      authenticationScheme: query
      clientAuthenticationScheme: form
    resource:
      jwt:
        keyValue:
          -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
          ...
```

This is my server implementation:

**OAuth2Config:**

```
@Configuration
@EnableAuthorizationServer
public class OAuth2Config extends AuthorizationServerConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Value("${resource.id:spring-boot-application}")
    private String resourceId;

    @Value("${access_token.validity_period:3600}")
    int accessTokenValiditySeconds = 3600;

    //todo
    private static final String JWTSecretKey = "mySecretKey";

    @Autowired
    private AuthenticationManager authenticationManager;

    @Bean
    public TokenEnhancer tokenEnhancer()
    {
        return new JwtTokenEnhancer();
    }

    @Bean
    protected JwtAccessTokenConverter accessTokenConverter()
    {
        //todo use secure cert
        KeyStoreKeyFactory keyStoreKeyFactory = new KeyStoreKeyFactory(new ClassPathResource("jwt.jks"), JWTSecretKey.toCharArray());
        JwtAccessTokenConverter converter = new JwtAccessTokenConverter();

        converter.setKeyPair(keyStoreKeyFactory.getKeyPair("jwt"));
        return converter;
    }

    @Bean
    public TokenStore tokenStore()
    {
        return new JwtTokenStore(accessTokenConverter());
    }

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer endpoints) throws Exception
    {
        TokenEnhancerChain tokenEnhancerChain = new TokenEnhancerChain();
        tokenEnhancerChain.setTokenEnhancers(
                Arrays.asList(tokenEnhancer(), accessTokenConverter()));

        endpoints
                .tokenStore(tokenStore())
                .tokenEnhancer(tokenEnhancerChain)
                .authenticationManager(this.authenticationManager);      //only needed for password grant, which we should only use in case of native/client side apps

    }

    @Override
    public void configure(ClientDetailsServiceConfigurer clients) throws Exception
    {
        //todo add redirect urls
        clients.inMemory()
                .withClient("trusted-app")          //todo for postman testing only, remove in production!
                .secret("secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("client_credentials")
                .authorities("ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .resourceIds(resourceId, "myprintforce")
                .autoApprove(true)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenValiditySeconds)
                .and()
                .withClient("client")
                .secret("secret")
                .authorizedGrantTypes("password", "authorization_code", "refresh_token", "implicit")
                .authorities("ROLE_CLIENT", "ROLE_TRUSTED_CLIENT")
                .scopes("read", "write")
                .resourceIds("client", resourceId)
                .autoApprove(true)
                .accessTokenValiditySeconds(accessTokenValiditySeconds);
        ;
    }
}
```

**TokenEnhancer**

```
public class JwtTokenEnhancer implements TokenEnhancer
{
    @Override
    public OAuth2AccessToken enhance(OAuth2AccessToken accessToken, OAuth2Authentication authentication)
    {
        Map<String, Object> additionalInfo = new HashMap<>();
        additionalInfo.put("user", authentication.getName());
        ((DefaultOAuth2AccessToken) accessToken).setAdditionalInformation(additionalInfo);
        return accessToken;
    }
}
```

**WebSecurityConfig**

```
@Configuration
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter
{

    @Override
    public void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception
    {
        auth.inMemoryAuthentication().withUser("u").password("p").roles("USER");
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and()
                .formLogin()
                    .loginPage("/login")
                    .permitAll()
                    .and();
    }

    @Override
    @Bean
    public AuthenticationManager authenticationManagerBean() throws Exception
    {
        return super.authenticationManagerBean();
    }

}
```

**Application**

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class OAuthServerApplication extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        SpringApplication.run(OAuthServerApplication.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    public void addViewControllers(ViewControllerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addViewController("/login").setViewName("login");
    }
}
```

Comment: Why is it always that after days of trying and searching when you decide to post a stack overflow question you fix your own problem within an hour or so... Perhaps I should start posting questions earlier :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the 2 servers use the same (localhost) machine. When they have different contextPaths the problem is almost solved.

By changing some entries from the config file I got it to work.

I removed: `authenticationScheme: query` and `clientAuthenticationScheme: form` and added `scope=read`

It now looks like this:

```
security:
  oauth2:
    client:
      clientId: client
      clientSecret: secret
      accessTokenUri: http://localhost:12000/authentication/oauth/token
      userAuthorizationUri: http://localhost:12000/authentication/oauth/authorize
      scope: read
    resource:
      jwt:
        keyValue:
          -----BEGIN PUBLIC KEY-----
```